# How to sanitize post title with commas

Tags: title, get-the-title

I need to sanitize WordPress title with commas that is using commas to replace the spaces.

i used this but didn't worked for me

```
echo sanitize_title_with_commas("the_title");
```

What i mean is:

if this is the main title `this is WordPress forum` when I use the code it will become `this,is,wordpress,forum`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use http://php.net/manual/ro/function.str-replace.php?

Comment: sir i don't understand

Comment: $title = str_replace (' ' , ',' , $title);

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are outputting the title, the answer is different. But there are two possibilities.

### By Using `wp_title();`

If your theme is using the `wp_title();` function in its `header.php` file, you can use the `wp_title` filter. However, this function is being deprecated since 4.4.

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_the_title' );
function filter_the_title( $title ) {
    $title = str_replace( ' ', ',' , $title);
    return $title;
}
```

### By Using `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`

Newer themes add this method to enable the title tag support. If this is your case, you can use the `pre_get_document_title` filter to do so.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'filter_the_title' );
function filter_the_title( $title ) {
    $title = str_replace( ' ', ',' , $title);
    return $title;
}
```